# Flask + gRPC trouble

Tags: python, flask, grpc, grpc-python

I've got a flask API application running on Win by apache + mod_wsgi plugin.
I made a grpc service by official tutorials, created grpc server and running it as a win service (by some win service manager, can't find it anymore). As grpc client i used a flask endpoint:

```
@web.route( '/services/<service_name>', methods=[ 'POST' ] )
def run_service( service_name ):
    #flask response object, little desinged
    resp = EmptyResp()
    try:
        chan = grpc.insecure_channel( 'my.secret.ip:6066' )
        stub = rpc.gen.services_pb2_grpc.ServicesStub( chan )
        #here just trying to find existed method, they got an Empty messasge, can't find a good solution
        rpcResp = stub.__getattribute__( service_name )( rpc.gen.services_pb2.Empty() )
        #my func to decorate response
        resp.data = ObjResp( rpcResp.state )
    except NameError as NErr:
        print( NErr )
        resp.status_code = 404
        resp.data = ErrResp( 'Cannot get RPC generated files')
    except AttributeError as AErr:
        print( AErr )
        resp.status_code = 404
        resp.data = ErrResp( 'Where is no \'%s\' method or problem with RPC files' % service_name )
    except grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError as ErrConnRPC:
        print( ErrConnRPC )
        resp.status_code = 503
        resp.data = ErrResp( 'Cannot connect with RPC service' )
    finally:
        chan.close()
    return resp
```

So, the problem is that first request to that endpoint is completes with 200 and return of RPC method.
But further requests to **any endpoint of api** are not responding at all. No HTTP timeout error, no crushes of application at all, no attemts to run a flask or gRPC methods (i used print() for that). Just infinite loading. Repairs only by restarting both gRPC and Apache services.

I cannot find any solution to deploy gRPC servers, somy questions are:
1) What the reason why 2+ requests are not responding;
2) What is correct way to deploy gRPC servers on Win?
3) [Optional] In this row: `stub.__getattribute__( service_name )( rpc.gen.services_pb2.Empty() )` is there an option to do it better way?

Comment: There's nothing obviously suspicious with your gRPC code (except the usage of the private `_InactiveRpcError`class). What is your application doing when it's unresponsive to requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues running grpc clients with apache + mod_wsgi, the reason seems because of how processes are forked (and there are known issues with grpc-python on forking)

Refs:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/13050